# How to show $X := \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}X_n$ is a locally convex space.

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

My textbook on functional analysis says as follows.(The book is written in Japanese, ISBN: 978-4-946552-18-2)

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of locally convex spaces over $K (= \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$).
Suppose that $X_n$ is a subvector space of $X_{n+1}$, and the topology of $X_n$ is identical with the relative topology of $X_{n+1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Then $\displaystyle X := \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}X_n$ is a vector space by
addition $f_{a}$:  $X \times X \to X$
scalar product $f_{s}$: $K \times X \to X$,
where since for any $x, y \in X$, there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $x, y \in X_{n_0}$, we define $f_a(x, y) :=$ "the addition of $x$ and $y$ in $X_{n_0}$"(well-defined), and $f_s$ is also defined in the same way.

Furthermore, $X$ is a locally convex space if we equip $X$ with the topology which is generated by the following basis of neighborhoods of $x_0 \in X$:
\begin{equation}
x_0 + \{U \subset X \mid \textrm{$U$ is absolutely convex,} 
\\ \textrm{ and $U \cap X_n$ is a neighborhood of the origin of $X_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$}\}
\end{equation}

I don't know why $X$ is a locally convex space.
To show $X$ is a locally convex space, we have to show the continuity of $f_a$ and $f_s$, 
but I can't do that. Could anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Definition of a term:
$U \subset X$ is absolutely convex $\iff$ For $\lambda \in K$ satisfying $|\lambda| \leq 1$, $\lambda U \subset U$ and for $x, y \in U$ and $t \in [0, 1]$, $tx + (1-t)y \in U$

Comment: What is the definition you are working with for a locally convex space?

Comment: I write the definition below.  
Let $X$ be a vector space over $K = (\mathbb{R} or \mathbb{C})$.
Then $X$ is called a locally convex space if the next two conditions are satisfied:
(i) $X$ is equipped with the topology which makes the addition:$X \times X \to X$ and the scalar product:$K \times X \to X$ continuous
(ii) $X$ has a fundamental basis of neighborhoods of the origin consisting of convex sets.  

Just for the record, I also know LCS(locally convex space) is characterized with seminorms.

Comment: So you're fine with the second condition but want to verify the first condition (that it is a topological vector space)?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I have trouble in showing that $X$ is a TVS(topological vector space).

Comment: I think this would be simplest showing with nets (assuming you are okay with nets).

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I'm somewhat familiar with it.
Please give me a little time. I will try to show using nets.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/905557) I have elaborated on the conditions a family of sets must satisfy for it to be a neighbourhood basis of $0$ in a vector space topology. (For the scalar field $\mathbb{R}$; to treat complex vector spaces, the intervals in the discussion have to be replaced with disks, everything else carries over verbatim.) The pertinent result is that every family $\mathscr{B}$ of absolutely convex absorbing sets defines a unique vector space topology in which the family $\{ r\cdot B : r > 0, B \in \mathscr{B}\}$ is a neighbourhood basis of $0$. This topology

Comment: is locally convex. It is Hausdorff if and only if for every $x\in X\setminus \{0\}$ there is a $B \in \mathscr{B}$ and an $r > 0$ with $x \notin r\cdot B$. [Some authors require a vector space topology to be Hausdorff - for vector space topologies this is equivalent to $T_1$ or even to $T_0$. If that is the case, we need to add this condition.] This shows that the topology given on $X$ indeed is a locally convex vector space topology. For this we don't even need the compatibility of the topologies on the $X_n$.

Comment: The compatibility condition gives us that the subspace topology induced from $X$ on $X_n$ coincides with the given topology on $X_n$. For every absolutely convex neighbourhood $U_n$ of $0$ in $X_n$, there is an absolutely convex neighbourhood $U_{n+1}$ of $0$ in $X_{n+1}$ with $X_n \cap U_{n+1} = U_n$. Extending further, we obtain an absolutely convex absorbing $U \subset X$ with $X_k \cap U = U_k$ for all $k \geqslant n$.

Comment: Though I tried nets, I couldn't. But as a result, with the help of Daniel Fischer san's post, I understood X is a LCS. Daniel san, your explanation was very scrupulous and easy to understand. Thank you all very much, Keen-ameteur san and Daniel Fischer san. Since nothing hasn't written as an answer, not a comment, I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to show that in almost the same way as that in [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904559/convex-interior-topology/905557#905557), replacing the argument in $\mathbb{R}$ with that in $\mathbb{C}$. Though when you see the linked page, you will know, remarking "$U \cap X_n$ is a neighborhood of the origin of $X_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$" implies $U$ is absorbing, my claim also easily follows from the proposition proved in the link.